# answer type detection in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have searched so many research papers. but I did not find a good procedure to do this.

how to identify the question type and answer type detection in natural language processing with out using entity recognition?

Comment: What is 'question type' and 'answer type'? Examples?
And why 'without entity recognition'?

Comment: we try to make a question answering system.question is given to the system as a text.  so system  need to identify the question type .... that's what i mean ...

Answer (score 1):

Question type classification is generally approached like any other text classification problem, thus there is a wide variety of algorithms from simple Naive Bayes to convolutional neural networks that can do this task without additional preprocessing (see for example [this paper]][1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5882v2.pdf) for review of conventional methods for question type classification and [this one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5882v2.pdf) for example application of convnets). Perfomance, of course, may vary depending on your task specifics.